# Gemfile lacks in ruby on rails cloned project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I cloned a rails project from github and it lacks the gemfile and gemfile.lock
I have tried bundle install but it brings out ths error....
Could not locate the gemfile...
How do I go about it??

Comment: do the gemfile \ gemfile.lock files exist in the github repo..?

Comment: Which project? If you share the github link, it'll be easier to debug

Comment: can you see the `gemfile` in the repository? What is in `.gitignore` ?